# Launching Chromium on startup with systemd

Tags: boot, systemd, opensuse

**Task**: Start Chromium on startup on openSUSE machine

**Problem**: I think the problem is that I want to start a GUI program

**So far**:

```
Mon Aug 14; 06:45:00; marton;/etc/systemd ;  $  
Mon Aug 14; 06:45:00; marton;/etc/systemd ;  $  ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  529 Mar 15 07:20 bootchart.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  138 Aug 14 06:34 chorm_start.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  768 Mar 15 07:20 journald.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  709 Mar 15 07:20 logind.conf
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  772 Aug 14 05:16 system
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1196 Mar 15 07:20 system.conf
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Mar 15 07:20 user
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  992 Mar 15 07:20 user.conf
Mon Aug 14; 06:45:00; marton;/etc/systemd ;  $  sudo chmod 664 chorm_start.service 
root's password:
Mon Aug 14; 06:45:19; marton;/etc/systemd ;  $  ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  529 Mar 15 07:20 bootchart.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  138 Aug 14 06:34 chorm_start.service
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  768 Mar 15 07:20 journald.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  709 Mar 15 07:20 logind.conf
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  772 Aug 14 05:16 system
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1196 Mar 15 07:20 system.conf
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Mar 15 07:20 user
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  992 Mar 15 07:20 user.conf
Mon Aug 14; 06:45:20; marton;/etc/systemd ;  $  cat chorm_start.service                      
[Unit]                                                                                       
Description="Starting chromium on startup"                                                   

[Service]                                                                                    
ExecStart=/usr/lib64/chromium/chromium                                                       

[Install]                                                                                    
WantedBy=multi-user.target                                                                   
Mon Aug 14; 06:45:38; marton;/etc/systemd ;  $  sudo systemctl status chorm_start
chorm_start.service - "Starting chromium on startup"                                         
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/chorm_start.service; enabled)                                
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-08-14 06:38:44 EEST; 7min ago           
  Process: 853 ExecStart=/usr/lib64/chromium/chromium (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 853 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 14 06:38:47 date chromium[853]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Aug 14 06:38:47 date chromium[853]: [853:853:0814/063844.727638:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] Gtk: cannot open display:
Mon Aug 14; 06:46:35; marton;/etc/systemd ;  $
```

**Question**: What am I doing wrong and how to solve the problem

Comment: You'll have to provide the screen for chrome to connect to. Do you want it to pop-up on your (automatically opened) desktop? On some virtual X display?

Comment: Why does it need to be started by systemd? This just seems to propogate the systemd madness.

Comment: @Anthon I want it to pop on my desktop(cntrl + alt + F7)

Comment: @symcbean well, I heard crontab is not a good idea, there is rc.local or something like that which is hard to pull off because the internet is flooded with Debian solutions ONLY and systemd looks easy and universal for every distro

Comment: rc.local is not the place to start up interactive programs (except for possible [x|k|g]dm). While systemd provides an interface for *everything* that still makes it the wrong place to start the program. The browser is dependent on a user session and you need to ensure the latter is in place - the easiest way to do that is by starting it from the session.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## And now, the systemd answer.

Since you did ask how to do it with systemd.  ☺

This is how the systemd people have been telling people to do this.

You are putting the service unit file in entirely the wrong directory.  It should not go in `/etc/systemd`.  It should not even go in `/etc/systemd/system`.  It should go in `~marton/.config/systemd/user`.

This is because a graphical program that you want to run under the aegis of your own account is a *per-user* service not a *system* service.  (You are currently invoking a WWW browser as the superuser.  That is a very bad idea.  Stop that *now*!)  You *could* configure it for *all* users in the `/etc/systemd/user` directory, but it is probable that not all users on your machine need to start Chromium as a service.  So configure it just for your user account, specifically.

As it is a per-user service, you should manipulate it with the `--user` option to `systemctl`, sans `sudo`.  For example:

```
systemctl --user status chrome.service
```

That goes for enabling and disabling it, too.

As a per-user service unit, it should be `WantedBy=default.target`, because there is no `multi-user.target` for per-user services.  (Although I suspect it should *actually* be `WantedBy=your-desktop-session.target`, which will be something like `gnome-session.target` depending from what desktop your are using.  What the systemd people have been saying is not wondrously clear on this point.)

And one part of the systemd people's bodge to make per-user services look like per-login-session services is the whole `graphical-session` mechanism, which your service unit must incorporate with the setting:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=graphical-session.target
```

What else you have to do depends from how far OpenSuSE has got with the whole `graphical-session` bodge, which systemd people started pushing in 2016.  Ubuntu and Debian provide a whole mess of behind the scenes shell scripting in GUI login session startup and shutdown that bodges both the starting/stopping of `graphical-session.target` and injecting the `DISPLAY` environment variable.  If your OpenSuSE does not yet have this, you might have to fill in that part.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering et al. (2016).  [systemd.special](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- Martin Pitt (2016-07-25). *[units: add graphical-session.target user unit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/3678)*.  systemd bug #3678.
- Martin Pitt (2016-09-29). *[graphical-session.target](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hq18daxTkLA)*.  systemd.conf.  Youtube.
- Ian Lane (2017-07-30). *[systemd in GNOME user sessions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyadP17NUFQ)*.  GUADEC 2017.  Youtube.

Comment: What is the recommended way to run a proccess on startup?

Comment: @Hartun Systemd is the way to run a process on *startup* these days. But you don't want to run a process on startup, you want to run a process on *login*, which is a completely different thing. The recommended way to start a process on GUI login to add it to your desktop environment's autostart applications.

Comment: Until `graphical-session.target` arrives for Debian, have a look [here](https://superuser.com/a/1128905/383800).

Answer (score 4):

In short (additionally to [JdeBP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/385979/105615)):

1. **Never ever use `root` if not absolutely needed.** Least of all for the browser since most of the myriad bugs in them would result in direct root access to the attacker.
2. Put your systemd files in `~/.config/systemd/user`
3. Enable: E.g. `systemctl --user enable firefox`

`~/.config/systemd/user/firefox.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Firefox
PartOf=graphical-session.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/firefox
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

This should start Firefox at boot.

---

If `graphical-session.target` is not the right for you (since there is something other managed by the login manager, your display manager or Google knows what) have a look at `systemctl --user status *.target` what other there might be.

---

If `graphical-session.target` is not active after graphical login (you might have an old or *stable* system), you can manually start it by adding the following to your `~/.xsessionrc`:

```
systemctl --no-block --user start graphical-session.target
```

Comment: Command `systemctl --no-block --user start graphical-session.target` does not work because of `RefuseManualStart=yes` in `graphical-session.target`.  It is required to create intermediate target, e.g. `my-session.target` with lines: 
`[Unit]
Description=My X11 session
DefaultDependencies=no
RefuseManualStart=no

BindsTo=graphical-session.target
Before=graphical-session.target` 
Then you can run `systemctl --no-block --user start my-session.target`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this myself, and like you found that `systemd` is the wrong tool for the job when it comes to starting graphical desktop apps. An easy approach is to use the "autostart apps" feature of your preferred desktop environment.

The difference is that `systemd` does not have easy access to the `DISPLAY` environment variable, while the "auto start apps" approach will.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me. The key is to add the `User` in the `Service`, along with initiating the `DISPLAY` in the `Environment` .

```
[Unit]
Description=launch chromium

[Service]
User=<user>
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/chromium-browser

[Install]
WantedBy=user@.service
```

Comment: The answer implies that this snippet and hence the browser is being run as root what [JdeBP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/385979/105615) already said to be a horrible idea. Instead, run it via `systemctl --user` and kick out the `User=` and `Environment=`, change `WantedBy=` to `graphical-session.target`.

Comment: @Suuuehgi `man systemd.exec(5)` says: `User=, Group= Set the UNIX user or group that the processes are executed as, respectively.` Simple experimentation confirms this. `sudo systemd-run --pty -p User=jdoe whoami` prints `jdoe`, _not_ `root`. It may be unwanted on a multi-user system to start a _system_ unit to run an application using a random user (i.e. all other users will run the app as the specified user), but the application is emphatically not running as root.