# My systemd service won't run

Tags: linux, systemd, thinkpad, xinput, libinput

I am trying to set xinput settings on my laptop on boot so I made a script with all my settings and a basic systemd service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sets my preferred xinput settings

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/SCRIPTS/xinput.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I ran `systemctl enable xinput-settings.service` but that doesn't work, nor does `systemctl start` but running `sudo bash /usr/local/bin/SCRIPTS/xinput.sh` (the script requires root) works fine but this systemd service won't. I tried setting user to root and some other fixes I saw but nothing fixes it.

Here is the script contents:

```
xinput --set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" 320 -0.4
exit 0
```

I am using Arch Linux kernel 5.6.12-arch1-1

`systemctl status xinput-settings` says:

```
● xinput-settings.service - Sets my preferred xinput settings
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/xinput-settings.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-05-15 23:34:35 +04; 42ms ago
    Process: 16809 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/SCRIPTS/xinput.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 16809 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

May 15 23:34:35 ThinkX250 systemd[1]: Started Sets my preferred xinput settings.
May 15 23:34:35 ThinkX250 systemd[16809]: xinput-settings.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
May 15 23:34:35 ThinkX250 systemd[16809]: xinput-settings.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/SCRIPTS/xinput.sh: No such file or directory
May 15 23:34:35 ThinkX250 systemd[1]: xinput-settings.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
May 15 23:34:35 ThinkX250 systemd[1]: xinput-settings.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: It might not work because `systemd` command does not exist. You probably wanted to use `systemctl` command instead. Also, `…enable xinput-settings.service` is not supposed to run the service right now, it enables it to run on boot. Another problem is calling `exit 0` in the end. You don't want this because you won't know if `xinput` failed for some reason *(which it well may because you use numeric ID instead of a property name in `xinput` call, and those may change)*. What does `systemctl start xinput-settings && systemctl status xinput-settings` say?

Comment: Although I stand corrected, [there is a binary called `systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html). But it is for internal use and does not have the `enable` or `start` options. On my system it is not in $PATH too.

Comment: @K7AAY I am using Arch Linux kernel 5.6.12-arch1-1, will edit

Comment: @Hi-Angel sorry, i meant systemctl.

Comment: updated post with what systemctl status says.

Comment: `xinput` will not work since it isn't specified which X server to connect to (if any would be running when the unit is ran). It would be better to either edit the [X server configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Configuration) or to run your script from your display manager

Comment: Regarding the error you see in `systemctl status`, try adding full path to `xinput`, which is `/usr/bin/xinput` on Archlinux. However as noted by Torin, indeed if the service will be executed before X server launched, this won't work. I.e. you may make it work right now *(e.g. by adding `DISPLAY=:0` if needed)*, but the next time you boot it gonna fail anyway.

Comment: Add `Environment="DISPLAY=:0"` to the `[Service]` section to specify a display, and add `After=graphical.target` to the `[Unit]` section to ensure this doesn't start up before your x-server is running. Also consider adding `Type=oneshot` and `RemainAfterExit=yes` to your `[Service]` section so that the service considers itself started for your whole session.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks. I'll try what you said.

Comment: Weird, adding DISPLAY=:0 and trying to use the full path have the same error with not being able to find the file.

Comment: Well KDE autostart made it work. I didn't know KDE could autostart

Comment: The script does not have a shebang or executable bit set?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this service unit instead:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sets my preferred xinput settings

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/SCRIPTS/xinput.sh
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Line by line explanation:

- `Type=oneshot` is suitable for scripts which are executed once and then end.  If you don't specify this, `Type=simple` is defaulted and systemd may be surprised that your service ended so quickly.  I think that's probably the first reason why you had `Active: failed`
- `Environment="DISPLAY=:0"`. You can have several users logged in and several displays active at a time. systemd isn't attached to a desktop/display so if it runs xinput, xinput will fail.  By setting this environment variable, you are telling xinput which display to use
- `RemainAfterExit=yes`. Not strictly necessary, but I like this for `oneshot` types. It means when the service is complete its status will be `active (exited)` instead of `inactive (dead)`.
- `WantedBy=graphical.target` means that this service will be started after the xserver starts.

If you still have problems, it may be related to the xauthority.  In that case, see a good answer here:

[Setting DISPLAY in systemd service file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85244/setting-display-in-systemd-service-file)

Comment: Thank you but this has the same error as in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my script to KDE autostart worked even with sudo.