# Issue with correctly running a systemd service file

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, x11, java

I have a GUI program that I can run from a terminal with no issue using:

```
$ /home/user1/ibg/ibg username=*** password=***
```

With the above command, the program GUI is displayed, get automatically logged-into my online account, and I can communicate with their server through port 4002 using a python script and successfully request data. No issue.

I would like to create a service for the above command using `systemd` in ubuntu. The service file I wrote is as follows (placed in `/etc/systemd/system`):

```
[Unit]
Description=ibg service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/home/user1/ibg/ibg username=**** password=****

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, the service cannot be run successfully.

```
user1@SFO:~$ sudo systemctl status ibg.service
● ibg.service - ibg service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ibg.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-08-18 22:13:07 PDT; 3s ago
  Process: 27951 ExecStart=/home/user1/ibg/ibg username=**** password=**** (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 27951 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 18 22:13:07 SFO ibg[27951]:         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Aug 18 22:13:07 SFO ibg[27951]:         at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
Aug 18 22:13:07 SFO ibg[27951]:         at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1734)
Aug 18 22:13:07 SFO ibg[27951]:         at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1266)
Aug 18 22:13:07 SFO ibg[27951]:         at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.handleFailure(LauncherEngine.java:140)
Aug 18 22:13:07 SFO ibg[27951]:         at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:94)
Aug 18 22:13:07 SFO ibg[27951]:         at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.start(UnixLauncher.java:66)
Aug 18 22:13:07 SFO ibg[27951]:         at install4j.ibg.GWClient.main(Unknown Source)
Aug 18 22:13:07 SFO systemd[1]: ibg.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 18 22:13:07 SFO systemd[1]: ibg.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Could someone help me how I can track down where the issue is? The status command does not provide why the service cannot be run. Is there any way to get more info on the failure? What could be the difference between running the command line version of the GUI with the service I created? I am using the exact same command to run it with `ExecStart`.

Comment: Try `journalctl -u ibg.service` to see the full log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a graphical application, I suspect this answer may help you:

[Setting DISPLAY in systemd service file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85244/setting-display-in-systemd-service-file)

You have a few problems with your service file as it's running a graphical application.

If you want to keep it as a system service:

- It's `WantedBy=multi-user.target`.  I recommend changing to `WantedBy=graphical.target` and `After=graphical.target` which should only happen after your display manager starts.  However, it may still be a problem as it might try (and fail) to start the application before you log in.
- It's running as `root`.  You might want to set `User=` in the service section
- Add `Environment=DISPLAY=:0` and `Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/username/.Xauthority`.

It might work better as a user service:

- move `*.service` to `~/.config/systemd/user/`
- change `WantedBy=` to `WantedBy=default.target`

Once it is a user-service, enable it with `systemctl --user enable ibg.service` or start it with `systemctl --user start ibg.service`.

Comment: I modified my unit file based on your answer and did `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`, and started the service but I get the error `Failed to start ibg.service: Unit ibg.service not found.`. In addition to this, I also verified the service file and got `sudo systemd-analyze verify ibg.service
/etc/systemd/system/vncserver2.service:9: Unknown lvalue 'WorkinDirectory' in section 'Service'
Attempted to remove disk file system, and we can't allow that.`

Comment: Ubuntu only finds `ibg.service` when I move it to `/etc/systemd/system`. Neither `/etc/systemd/user` nor `~/.config/systemd/user/` would allow me to have the service file found.

Comment: When you put it in `~/.config/systemd/user/`, you need to use `systemctl --user` to work with it.  Editing the answer to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Works great! One quick question, is there anyway to send an ENTER from the service? When my GUI opens, there is an informational dialogue box on top of the main window that I have to click on OK or hit ENTER on the keyboard to close the informational dialogue box and have the GUI actually started. Could `systemd` provide such capability?

Comment: systemd doesn't do that natively, but you could always add an `ExecStartPost=` command to run a script to do it for you.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3800208/1723954

Comment: I tried `systemctl --user enable ibg.service` but I got `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`. I added `User=myuser` but still get the same error after `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and using `sudo systemctl --user enable ibg.service`.

Comment: When you use `--user`, you don't need to use `sudo`.

Comment: Great! That fixed my issue. Thank you for that. It seems like I should use the following commands for user services: `systemctl --user daemon-reload` and `systemctl --user start ibg.service`