How to get the gpg password prompt from a user's systemd timer unit?
I've written a short script to copy and encrypt my home dir for backup. I do this using
gpg --symmetric

I call this from my backup.service file, and it works fine: when I run systemctl --user start backup.service from gnome-terminal, I get a graphical prompt to enter the password for encryption, and I see an output file created successfully.
However, when I put this in a backup.timer unit, and try to run that with systemctl --user start backup.timer :
~/bin$ systemctl --user status backup.timer
● backup.timer - Daily backup schedule
     Loaded: loaded (/home/xxx/.config/systemd/user/backup.timer; disabled; vendor preset: en>
     Active: active (waiting) since Fri 2024-09-06 15:13:34 CEST; 6s ago
    Trigger: Sat 2024-09-07 00:00:00 CEST; 8h left
   Triggers: ● backup.service

It just hangs like this, and the password prompt dialog doesn't appear.
I'm guessing that timer units don't have access to the environment.
I've checked that necessary variables like XAUTHORITY and DISPLAY are set via systemctl --user show-environment.
What can I do to troubleshoot this?
For completeness, I have created a minimal reproducible example. These are the files:
~$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/test-password.service
[Unit]
Description=Test password prompt

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'dd if=/dev/zero count=100 | gpg --symmetric > /tmp/test.gpg'

and
~$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/test-password.timer
[Unit]
Description=Test password prompt timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target


So I noticed that the systemctl status *.timer will always show active (waiting) regardless of the service completion. i.e. it indicates the status of the timer, not the underlying service. I take this to mean it's just "waiting for the next scheduled runtime", rather than "waiting for the process to complete".

I got this working by following a similar approach to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/653101/93914 . In gnome, I search for startup applications and created a command
systemctl --user import-environment XAUTHORITY DISPLAY

I've not marked this as the correct answer, as I'm not convinced that this is safe; if the systemd timer is run before the gnome startup script executes, I think this will fail.
Perhaps putting it under /etc/profile.d? But essentially I need a way to ensure that this is run before the timers are run, but after gdm has started.
In summary, it appears that the *.timer does not inherit the desktop environment variables, vs *.service, which does, and the way to fix this is using systemctl import-environment.
