# Error when running X11 application as root

Tags: x11, root, su

I get this wierd error when I run applications as root.

```
**(gedit:630): WARNING **: could not open X display
No protocol specified
Unable to init server

(gedit:630): Gtk-WARNING **: Cannot open display: :0.0
```

I'm using Arch Linux. I use `su -` to login as root. And this error comes when im running the X server. Also if i copy `.Xauthority` into the `/root/` it works without error.

Answer (score 1):

It is really unclear with your question's current state.

I believe you have to export the display.

```
export DISPLAY='IP:0.0'
```

See the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/310201/252686).

Check the server's sshd_config (normally `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), and make sure the `X11Forwarding` option is enabled with the line

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

If `X11Forwarding` is not specified, the default is no.

Comment: ok wait i dont have ssh/ folder. im using arch linux, i don't have openssh installed on my computer!

Comment: im actually trying this on a live-CD its a remastered iso. other thing after booting the iso. if i login to root run startx and logout then come back to normal user then it works great, this error doesn't come up.

Comment: @Chronix01 please add these details to your original question. We need to know exactly how you're running as root (`sudo`? `su`? Login as root?), we need to know your OS and distribution, and we need to know if you are logged in physically or remotely and if there is a running X server when you get that error. Also have a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/438774/85695).

Answer (score 0):

Running `su -` erases almost all environment variables. GUI applications need two environment variables to know how to connect to the GUI environment: `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`. See [Open a window on a remote X display (why "Cannot open display")?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126) for a more detailed explanation. The command `su -` retains `DISPLAY` but not `XAUTHORITY`. So your GUI application knows where to connect, but doesn't have the requisite password (“cookie”).

Instead of logging in as root, just run the program without changing most environment variables: run `su`, not `su -`.

If you want to do complicated things, read [Can I launch a graphical program on another user's desktop as root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root/1600#1600)