# Run X program in another user's display

Tags: ssh, x11, xorg, remote, display

Running Ubuntu 16.04 in `host`, I have the following setup:

- a `user1`, who performed a GUI login in `host`;
- a `user2`, who is a `sudoer` and is logged in *only* through a text `ssh` connection (`ssh user2@host`).

I would like `user2` to run an X application, for example `xclock`, on the `user1` display. From `user1` perspective, this must be the same as when `user1` itself runs `xclock`.

The owner of the process `xclock` should be `user2`, because this is the user who launched it, but however this is **not important**.

**Edit**: I can use `sudo`, but I can not use `user1` password, which is unknown to me.

How to accomplish this?

---

I read [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10126/48707) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1600/48707), but they contain no direct examples about this. I also read about `~/.Xautority`, `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1` and I obtained the list of cookies with `xauth list`, but wasn't able to use them.

I tried, from the prompt in the `ssh` connection (so, as `user2`):

```
$ env DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/user1/.Xauthority xclock
```

but this causes the prompt to never return. Note that, being a `sudoer`, `user2` is potentially **able** to read/copy/write the file `.Xauthority` in `user1` home directory. The above commands, however, don't work even when `user2` and `user1` are the same.

Comment: Did you run `sudo su` or `sudo bash` before the `xclock` command?  `user2` may be a sudoer, but still needs to run `sudo` to get root privileges.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Neither of them, I ran the whole `xclock` line just as `user2`.

Comment: It is the same, after trying with `sudo bash` and then the command. The prompt does not return.

Comment: The prompt shouldn't return until `xclock` exits. Does `xclock` appear on user1's display?

Comment: @JigglyNaga You're right. However, in this case `xclock` doesn't appear.

Comment: You must export the var and run xclock as user1. I can't test with your config but it's ok on OpenBSD from root user on debian : su -l user1 -c 'export DISPLAY=:0.0;XAUTHORITY=/home/user1/XAUTHORITY;xclock&'

Comment: @ctac_ Thank you for your test. `su` would require the `user1` password, while instead I would like to use `sudo` from `user2`, so with `user2` password. It works with (I guess it is a sort of equivalent to your `su`):

`sudo -u user1 DISPLAY=:0 xclock &`

Comment: @ctac_ If (after these considerations) you want to write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Neither I am using `sudo`, ever, but the standard procedure to let another user on your display is to export the auth info with `xauth(1)`, not muck by hand with `~/.Xauthority`.

So, if `user1` is the one logged in on the display, the guest (`user2`) should run the following commands:

```
user2$ export DISPLAY=:0
user2$ ssh user1@localhost "xauth extract - $DISPLAY" | xauth merge -
user2$ xclock
```

`su` could be used instead of `ssh`:

```
user2$ su - user1 -c "xauth extract - $DISPLAY" | xauth merge -
```

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. As I said in the comments to the questions (but I'll now edit the question to make it more readable), I would like to use `sudo`, but not to use the `user1` password (I don't and shouldn't know it), which is required instead in your example.

Comment: You can replace the ssh or su with `sudo -u user1 xauth extract - $DISPLAY | ...`.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried with `sudo -u user1 -i xauth extract - $DISPLAY | ...` and it works.

Comment: @mosvy I am getting this error xauth:  `timeout in locking authority file /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority; xauth: (argv):1:  unable to read any entries from file "(stdin)"
` when I run `su secure -c "xauth extract - $DISPLAY" | xauth merge -`. Here my current UID is 1000, and UID for `secure` is 1001. Can you please make suggestion?

Comment: @Porcupine Try with `su - secure -c "...` (notice the dash between `su` and `secure`). That should prevent `su` from passing down the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable, which would cause both the extracting and the merging xauth to work on the same file, which is not what was intended.

Comment: @mosvy Whenn I did `$ su - secure -c "xauth extract - $DISPLAY" | xauth merge -` I got: `xauth:  file /home/secure/.Xauthority does not exist
No matches found, authority file "-" not written
xauth: (argv):1:  unable to read any entries from file "(stdin)"` Also, `echo $XAUTHORITY`  is blank for secure user.
`

Comment: I suggest you try giving the name of the xauth file explicitly via `-f`, instead of letting it guess it (wrong) via the user name and the `XAUTHORITY` envvar. Assuming that a) `secure` is the user logged into the display and its uid is 1001, try `su - secure -c "xauth -f /run/user/1001/gdm/Xauthority extract - $DISPLAY" | xauth merge -`.

Comment: Notice that --depending on your system (are you using Xwayland?)-- xauth & mit cookie authentication may [**not be used at all**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571101/xephyr-ac-dangerously/571152#comment1063234_571152); in that case, `su - secure -c 'DISPLAY=:0 xhost +si:localuser:your_user_name'` should give you access to the display `:0` if user `secure` is already logged in on that display.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to someone else's X11 session, you'll need the correct value for the `DISPLAY` environment variable and the contents of the other user's `~/.Xauthority` file.

If `user1` has logged in locally, their DISPLAY variable setting is almost always `:0.0`, as this is the first local X11 display.

As `user2`, you could do this:

```
export DISPLAY=':0.0'
sudo cp ~user1/.Xauthority $TMP/user1_Xauthority
sudo chown user2 $TMP/user1_Xauthority
export XAUTHORITY=$TMP/user1_Xauthority
xclock &
```

Since `DISPLAY=':0.0'` tells the X11 applications to connect to a *local* display through an UNIX socket located in `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`, these commands must be run on the same host that has the physical display.

Historically, the X11 protocol was originally designed to also allow connecting to the display over the network, using TCP port (6000 + display number), but this turned out to be not secure, and on modern Linux/Unix systems is usually disabled by default, so using something like `export DISPLAY=remotehost:0.0` to push your X11 application's output to the display connected to `remotehost` will not work unless specifically enabled (and enabling that is usually a bad idea).

Comment: Thanks for all your considerations, which are more clarifying about this. I tried as suggested, but it didn't work: `No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0.0`.

Comment: `~user1/.Xauthority` has permissions `600` and the owner is `user1`. When copied with `sudo cp ~user1/.Xauthority $TMP/user1_Xauthority`, the newly created file `$TMP/user1_Xauthority` has the same permissions, but the owner is `root`. So, at least to me, this example works only if `chown user2 $TMP/user1_Xauthority` is performed before launching `xclock`.

Comment: Oops, that's true. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

**All** the considerations in all the answers are useful, but none of the suggested commands is the solution asked for. Just for the sake of clarity, I try to provide it here.

The best approach seems to be the mosvy one, also because of the very restrictive permissions of the file `~user1/.Xauthority`.

The number of the active `DISPLAY`, used by `user1`, must be obtained first. It is available, for example, from the output of `who` and it is usually `:0`.

If `user2` is a `sudoer`, only his password is required, not `user1` password. From `user2` prompt:

```
user2$ export DISPLAY=:0
user2$ sudo -u user1 -i xauth extract - $DISPLAY | xauth merge -
user2$ xclock
```

Or (acting as `user1`):

```
user2$ sudo -u user1 DISPLAY=:0 xclock &
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a complete solution because i don't use sudo at all.
You must export DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY before running xclock as user1.

```
su -l user1 -c 'export DISPLAY=:0.0;XAUTHORITY=/home/user1/XAUTHORITY;xclock&'
```

Note that is not a durable solution because DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY are not always the same.